# Why ExceptionHandler does not work with junit?

Tags: java, spring, junit, exceptionhandler

I am having trouble to test a controller class with @ExceptionHandler annotation.

At first, my controller was like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@Tag(name = "User")
public class UserRestController {
    private final UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    @Operation(summary = "Update a User",
        requestBody = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
            description = "User to update",
            required = true,
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))
    ))
    @ApiResponses(
        value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Update Ok",
                content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Ressource not found",
                content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid input",
                content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error",
                content = @Content),
        }
    )
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser (@RequestBody User user) {

        try {
            userService.getUserById(user.getIdUser());
            User newUser = userService.updateUser(user);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(newUser);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

And my test :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRestController userController;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    private User user1;
    private User user2;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        user1 = new User();
        user1.setIdUser(1L);

        user2 = new User();
        user2.setIdUser(2L);
    }

    @Test
    void testUpdateUserInternalServerError() {
        Mockito.when(userService.updateUser(user1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        ResponseEntity<User> response = userController.updateUser(user1);
        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Here everything worked just fine, but I had a lot of duplication in my controller due to several methods with try/catch blocks, so I modified it to have :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@Tag(name = "User")
public class UserRestController {
    private final UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    @Operation(summary = "Update a User",
        requestBody = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
            description = "User to update",
            required = true,
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))
    ))
    @ApiResponses(
        value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Update Ok",
                content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Ressource not found",
                content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid input",
                content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error",
                content = @Content),
        }
    )
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser (@RequestBody User user) {
            userService.getUserById(user.getIdUser());
            User newUser = userService.updateUser(user);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(newUser);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleException(Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

When I start my application, everything is good, the exceptionHandler do its job and send a 500 response to my front app.
The problem is when I launch my test class I have an error :

```
10:55:49.308 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: class [UserRestControllerTest], method [testUpdateUserInternalServerError], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]
10:55:49.308 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.w.ServletTestExecutionListener - Resetting RequestContextHolder for test class com.open.myApp.back.controllers.UserRestControllerTest

java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.open.myApp.back.services.UserServiceImpl.updateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)
    at com.open.myApp.back.services.UserServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.updateUser(<generated>)
    at com.open.myApp.back.controllers.UserRestController.updateUser(UserRestController.java:81)
    at com.open.myApp.back.controllers.UserRestControllerTest.testUpdateUserInternalServerError(UserRestControllerTest.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to deal with that ?

Thanks for your Help.

I tried to mock the response of my repo instead of the one of my service, but the problem was still there.

**Problem solved!**

Thanks to the explanations of M. Deinum (see comments), I figured out what was the deal.
Here is my class test using MockMvc :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserRestControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<User> jsonUser;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static final String USER_1 = """
            {
                "idUser": "1"
            }
            """;

    private User user1;
    private User user2;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        user1 = new User();
        user1.setIdUser(1L);

        user2 = new User();
        user2.setIdUser(2L);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    void testUpdateUserInternalServerError() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(userService.updateUser(user1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        MockHttpServletResponse response = this.mockMvc.perform(put("/api/user/update")
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(USER_1)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn().getResponse();

        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfecetly, the problem is your test. You aren't using anything web related but are directly calling the method. Instead you should use something like either `MockMvc` or `TestRestTemplate` etc. to fire of a request and then handle the response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used MockMvc and everything's fine. I'll edit my post to give the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-servlet/exceptionhandlers.html):

> If an exception occurs during request mapping or is thrown from a
> request handler (such as a @Controller), the DispatcherServlet
> delegates to a chain of HandlerExceptionResolver beans to resolve the
> exception and provide alternative handling, which is typically an
> error response.

In other words, you need a bit more "Spring magic" than just your own controller to be able to process an exception in a proper handler. That's why you should use something like [MockMvc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

Thanks to the explanations of M. Deinum (see comments), I figured out what was the deal. Here is my class test using MockMvc :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserRestControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<User> jsonUser;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static final String USER_1 = """
            {
                "idUser": "1"
            }
            """;

    private User user1;
    private User user2;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        user1 = new User();
        user1.setIdUser(1L);

        user2 = new User();
        user2.setIdUser(2L);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    void testUpdateUserInternalServerError() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(userService.updateUser(user1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        MockHttpServletResponse response = this.mockMvc.perform(put("/api/user/update")
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(USER_1)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn().getResponse();

        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```